# Email functionality in .net web app cannot be implemented due to SMTP server credential problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, web-applications, smtpclient

I am developing a web app in .NET using MVC and need to implement a functionality to allow the user to send a mail from his `mail_id` to another. Both the mail ids are in the same domain. I am using the `System.Net.Mail` class. But I am facing problems since the SMTP server need the sender credentials. The solutions I came across says to use the `Net.NetworkCredentials` class to give the username and password. But doesn't that require the user to give his credentials to the server? Isn't it not preferable? Is that the correct way? I think I am missing some fundamentals here. *The app uses windows authentication to validate users.*

```
    try
    {
        string fromAddr = sender + "@microsoft.com";
        string toAddr = receiver + "@microsoft.com";
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtp_server_dns);
        //SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;            
        mail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddr);
        mail.To.Add(toAddr);
        mail.Subject = sub;
        mail.Body = body;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi - can you post the code you do have then people can better diagnose your problem

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use CredentialCache, and will need to pass the Exchange server name in its parameter.

Try similar to below:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.your-mailserver.com");
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

**Ignore from here - It was due to misinterpretation in the question**

Ideally, you should have the credentials for SMTP within the web.config file. Though there are no any drawbacks to specifying them straight-away in code. However, for better maintainability purpose, web.config is the ideal place where it is also easy to switch the network delivery mode (like, file system for testing environments).

Just similar to below -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="youremail@yourdomain.com">
      <network host="smtp.yourdomain.com" port="25" userName="yourUserName" password="yourPassword"/>
     </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
</configuration>
```

You also need to set "EnableSsl" property of the smtpClient object to true. Once hosted with Https protocol, your web server will connect with the smtp server in a secured way and the encryption will be handled by .NET.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But the thing is I need the user to send the mail. That is the 'from' address will be the users mail id. But I cannot ask for their credentials from them right. Is there any way to use the windows credentials used for user authentication in the starting?

Comment: oh ok! Sorry, i think I misinterpreted your question.